# passing multiple -D arguments to driver-java-options in spark-submit on windows

Tags: java, apache-spark

I am working on a windows machine trying to run spark-submit on a jar file that was given to me by a colleague, who had no trouble running it on his computer using the same command. The command looks like this:

```
spark-submit.cmd --driver-java-options "-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=y,address=5005 -DMASTERNODE=local" --class=MYCLASS file:///path/myjar.jar
```

However, when I run this I get the error:

> The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.

If I pass only the first argument, i.e.:

```
spark-submit.cmd --driver-java-options "-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=y,address=5005" --class=MYCLASS file:///path/myjar.jar
```

I get no error, regardless of whether or not I am using quotes. And it appears that the command is run successfully. However, when I try t pass two arguments to te commandas follows:

```
cmd /C spark-submit.cmd --driver-java-options -agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=y,address=5008 -DMASTERNODE=local --class=taka.pipelines.AnomalyTxTrainingPipeline file:///cygdrive/c/Users/paul/stream/build/libs/taka-stream-0.1.0-dev_pl-SNAPSHOT-all.jar
```

I get the error:

> Error: Unrecognized option: -DMASTERNODE=local

This is happening regardless of whether I execute the command from cygwin using the cmd function, or whether I execute it directly from the windows command prompt.

Coule someone please help me?

-Paul

Answer (score 2):

This is a bug of spark windows command scripts, it can not handle parameters with quotes, change spark-submit.cmd to the following:

`cmd /V /E /C ""%~dp0spark-submit2.cmd" %*"`

All the other windows command scripts in spark which contains

`cmd /V /E /C "<command>" %*`

has the same problem, fix it with the similar way above.

Comment: what is the `""%~dp0spark-submit2.cmd" %*"` doing exactly?

Comment: I think the quotes outside make Windows command parser parse command and parameter correctly. Without the quotes outside, Windows command parser recognize part of the parameter as the command. For example, run the command `spark-submit --driver-class-option "-Dfile.encoding=utf-8" --class <FooClass.jar>` will get the error message `'D:\software\spark-2.1.1-bin-hadoop2.7\bin\spark-submit2.cmd" --driver-class-option "-Dfile.encoding' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.`